# How to set "Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)" as unchecked by default on Publish Options?

Tags: publishing, cme

I was wondering if there is a way to set "Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)" option as un-selected/unchecked by default on the Publish options. 
Our users publish `bundles` and they mostly do not use this option. But, it is selected/checked by default in Tridion on publish whenever a `bundle` is selected for publish. This induces one extra click and a hassle for the user to remember everytime to unselect this option whenever they want to publish. So, I want to change the default option as not selected for "Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content)"

Please suggest if there is a way to set this as un-selected by default

Answer (score 3):

The only way would be to create a GUI extension that changes the default.

Alternatively, you could consider automating the publishing of the bundles, if that is applicable to your use cases.

Comment: The user will definitely like to publish and control the publish related stuff which is understandable. So, automation is definitely looking out of the equation. I wish this option was configurable

Answer (score 0):

You can try and test following hack

Note: **but it will be applicable to complete publishing system not just bundles, so if someone publish a structure group for example, it will publish all pages under it irrespective of  its publishing status (in-progress-saved pages as well) so its your/client decision whether you want to use it or not**

in your installation system go to `Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Views\Popups\Publish` and open `publish.ascx` and remove checked="checked" from line no 116 as shown below. don't forget to clear your browser cache.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As a rule of thumb for products which are not open source, I do not modify any product file because it creates hassles for me during upgrade/hotfix rollup etc. Also, as you said, it is a hack and it is called like that for a reason :)